# Customizing the height of a figure

Tags: floats, height

How do I to increase the height of a figure? and keeping its width like it's mention in the below code.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill{}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{images/cu_global_initial}\hfill{}
\caption{Diagramme de cas d'utilisation global initial}
\label{fg:diag_cu_glbl}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Additionally giving height and keepaspectration should do the trick, right?

Comment: If you want to center your image use `\centering`. The `\hfill` construction you show is a bit strange, the first `\hfill` will be discarded as it is at the start of the line, the second `\hfill` would make it flush left, except that the image is full width so there is no alignment possible.

Comment: Do you want to do "as if" the figure had a width of \linewidth and a given height, or do you want to zoom the figure up those two dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a code for both cases:

```
        \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}

        \usepackage{graphicx}

        \begin{document}
        Voici une figure :

        \begin{figure}[!h]
        \centering\fbox{\raisebox{0pt}[6cm]{\includegraphics{airepara}}}%[width=\linewidth]
        \caption{Diagramme de cas d'utilisation global initial
        \label{fg-aire}}
        \end{figure}

        Comme on le voit sur la figure \ref{fg-aire}, blablabla…

        S’il s’agit d’effectuer un zoom :

        \begin{figure}[!h]
        \centering\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height = 8cm, keepaspectratio]{airepara}}%
        \caption{Diagramme de cas d'utilisation global initial
        \label{fg-aire}}
        \end{figure}

        \end{document}
```

(replace "airepara" by any graphics file that TeX can fing on your system).

[image]